# Using Python and Anaconda on the same machine

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, anaconda

I just installed Anaconda on C:\Anaconda3 on the same computer where the old Python was installed on C:\Python34.

There are tools that manage [different version of Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) or [different versions of Anaconda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html#install-a-different-version-of-python), but I can't find anything that manages different versions of both Python and Anaconda on the same machine at the same time.

I was able to get both the old app to run with Python 3.4 and the new with Anaconda 3.5 using the 4 scripts below. Double clicking on each of them in sequence the two apps run without problems.

But I wasn't able to make one script to run both the apps at once, not even two scripts, one for the first app and one for the second. Any idea how I would solve this problem?

**Python1.cmd**

```
setx PATH "[...]C:\Python34[...]"
setx PYTHONPATH "C:\Python34"
setx PYTHONHOME "C:\Python34"
```

**Python2.cmd**

```
cd \OldFolder
C:\Python34\python app.py
```

**Anaconda1.cmd**

```
setx PATH "[...]C:\Anaconda3[...]"
setx PYTHONPATH "C:\Anaconda3"
setx PYTHONHOME "C:\Anaconda3"
```

**Anaconda2.cmd**

```
cd \NewFolder
C:\Python34\python app.py
```

Using `setx` works, but only if the script that executes the `setx` and the one that executes `python` are not the same (as in the 4 scripts above). Using `setx` on the same script is ignored by `Python` or `Anaconda`.

Using `set` on the same script where `python` is executed causes `python` to crash immediately. Here are the script and the error:

**PythonSet.cmd**

```
set PATH="[...]C:\Python34[...]"
set PYTHONPATH="C:\Python34"
set PYTHONHOME="C:\Python34"
cd \OldFolder
C:\Python34\python app.py
```

**Error**

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Comment: I'm probaby missing something, but I don't see the problem. I have multiple versions of python installed (Anaconda among them) and I simply run `path\to\python.exe app.py` and it works with each installation. I don't have any of pythons in `PATH` and I don't have  `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` configured.

Comment: Running the Anaconda app with Python environment crashes in `sre_compile.py`. Running the Python app with Anaconda environment crashes in `_collections_abc.py`. I had to set all the 3 variables in order to get rid of the errors.

Comment: I see. I don't have any of them set, which is why I never have that problem. Anyway, can you show the script with which this happens: "*Using set on the same script where python is executed causes python to crash immediately*"?

Comment: I only now noticed you use `setx`. That is the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `SETX`, which does not change the environment variable. It saves the enviroment variable value in registry, to be used in future processes.

In order to change the value in current process, use `SET`:

```
set PATH="[...]C:\Anaconda3[...]"
set PYTHONPATH="C:\Anaconda3"
set PYTHONHOME="C:\Anaconda3"
```

Comment: I tried that, as explained on the question, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear, but I tried both `setx` and `set`. `setx` has not effect on this session, but it allows it to work at the next, while `set` it causes it to crash on this session, while has no effect on the next.

Comment: That does not work for subsequent processes. You can do both `SET` and `SETX` to cover both, but honestly, if you ever need to use `SETX`, I believe you are going to have problems sooner or later. For example, if you try to run multiple pythons at the same time, that won't work.

Comment: I know, and I tried, but since `set` doesn't work and after installing Anaconda the server was a brick, I found that solution with `setx` and double execution. Now I will try to add all the libraries to Anaconda and get the old app to work in Anaconda, but in the meantime that's the only solution I found.

Comment: Is it possible that this: `set PATH="[...]C:\Anaconda3[...]"` actually results in both pythons on path? I mean, one of them in the `...` part?

Comment: No, each script has 3 folders for Python or Anaconda. Also, I don't think the problem is there, because with two delayed executions it works. But it doesn't with `set` on the same session.

Comment: You will have to debug it. Try printing the whole environment (`SET` without arguments) before the call to python, both when it works and when it does not. There has to be a difference there.

Comment: I can't, Python crashes before loading the script. Executing just `C:\Python34\python` without running any app, with the correct environment previously set by `setx` it starts the interactive environment, while with the wrong environment Python crashes immediately with the error described on the post. It doesn't give me a chance to debug.

Comment: Not in python, *before* calling python. Or even *instead* of calling python. Just print the enviornment to see how it is different.

Comment: The set returns the correct values, as expected. I see the same environment on the same session after the set as on the next session after the setx. But on the first case it crashes, on the second it works.